# Where is the longest steep run to use for training in the eastern United States?

Tags: running, training, long-distance-running

Steep being 12% grade or more, where is the longest steep run in the eastern United States?

Or more broadly, where is the best place to train in the eastern US for races like the Hardrock 100 or Pikes Peak Marathon?

In these races there are long stretches of +12% grade for 3, 4, 5 or more miles at a time.

Comment: Good question! If I lived in that part of the world I would be curious about that too.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about geography

Comment: @JJosaur If there is no trail or road to run on then it doesnt answer the question, may as well delete it than move it

Comment: Can you give me a specific location in a state? I can route plot something which may help.

Comment: @JJosaur This side of the Mississippi River, the eastern side of the country. I know its a big area but its worth alot to know were to train for fanastic runs like Nolans 14 and Hardrock 100. Even in the Rockies this kind of ascent doesnt exist everywhere which makes these two ascents in the eastern US even cooler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From researching, 
Mount Sterling run from Big Creek campground, NC is a pretty good trail rising about 4200 feet over 5.9 miles.
Also Mount Washington in NH is paved and rises 4700 feet over 7.5 miles.
Very cool possibly found another from Gatlinburg to Monte LeConte rising about 4000 feet over 7 miles. This is probably a well traveled trail as well which means faster running.

What others are out there??